# Cannot attach my Extent report in editable email plugin. My workspace in Jenkins job is empty. is that the reason?

Tags: email, jenkins, report, extent

Maven java Selenium Project. I have been building jobs successfully. But I cannot attach My report to send email to outlook.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8XX0.png)

I am able to add the report to the body of the email, which displays without any CSS. Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQCvI.png)

Answer (score 0):

In 'Editable Email Notification', ideally, you need to place the file to be attached in "workspace" of the job. & then use filename.extension in 'Attachments'.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl79T.png

If you are using a slave/agent node to build a job, you will find the workspace in root directory of agent node. -> Root_directory/workplace/job_name.

or you may find your job's workspace in "build.xml" of your job.(jenkins/jobs/job_name/builds/build_no/build.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue with no attachments in automated mail :)

Solution - update the url as per the location where file is generated .

Example - I created a job named - "AutoRunJob" -> Workspace -> File ( generating html )

my path in the editable email notification - **target/test-output/LoggerReport/dashboard.html**

[image]

**Note : In Case no emails are flowing check what triggers it is set to by clicking on advance settings inside editable email notification configurations .**